# Setting up the view for user repeating code .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

hey everyone i have a question.
in my view i have a table that i show records in. if the record is closed the design of the table changes. right now my im doing this by `@if(record closed) show <div></div> else show <div class="bg-danger"><div>`
the content of the two divs are identical but the second one has `bg-danger` there must be a way to get around this repeating content where i dont have to copy and paste the entire `div` for each scenario.
How should i achieve that? is there a better way of setting up the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional operator `?:`:

```
<div class="@(record closed?"":"bg-danger")"></div>
```

Here is [an official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) about conditional operator `?:`.